# Android- Rounding of Image OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an application that requires my images to be circular. The original image
are square or rectangular. This images are from the server. 
I retrieve this images then set it in my image views of 7 images that should be circular.

I used the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in loading my image.

This is the method for rounding my image.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

So in the `onLoadingComplete()` of UniversalImageLoader,
I did this `imageView.setImageBitMap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, pixel))`

It works fine, but from time to time i get `OutofMemoryError`. 
I found out in the [Android-Universal-Image-Loader (github).](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

`Avoid using RoundedBitmapDisplayer. It creates new Bitmap object with ARGB_8888 config for displaying during work.`

Is there another way to implement rounding of image without having to suffer OutOfMemoryError?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[UPDATE] : This is how i configured the ImageLoader.

```
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(
                        new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                                .showStubImage(R.drawable.default_user)
                                .resetViewBeforeLoading()
                                .cacheOnDisc()
                                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                                .build())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
                .imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(context, new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params)))
                .threadPoolSize(2)
                .build();

        // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration.
        imageLoader.init(config);
```

Comment: The `OutOfMemory` problem is due to the images being too large. Your additional processing simply exacerbates the issue.

Comment: oh i see. so i should have to sacrifice the image quality then..

Comment: Depending on what you're aiming to achieve.  If you're not displaying your images very large, you can load them already scaled.  Have a look at `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` - which allows you to load an image into a smaller bitmap.

Comment: i have already set that one in the configuration of the ImageLoader. I will update my question to include code for configuring the imageLoader